# Неожиданный вывод в консоль

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Начал изучать ассемблер (TASM,64x,Windows). В регистр `dx` положили переменную `Mess2`, а в консоль выводиться "Hello, World!". Почему?

```
CSEG segment
org 100h

Begin:

    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, offset Mess2
    int 21h
    int 20h

Message db 'Hello, World!$'
Mess2 db 'Hi$!'
CSEG ends
end Begin
```

[image: вывод]

Comment: `ds` надо инициализировать явно... правда точный синтаксис для tasm'овских com'jd на вскидку не припомню...

Comment: * поправлюсь... для `*.com`'ов инициализировать `ds` как раз не обязательно, но т.к. ты собираешь всё в `*.exe`, то это необходимо... учитывая, что ты добавляешь смещение в начала файла, достаточно будет просто собрать его в `*.com`, а не `*.exe`...

Comment: Это пример кода из книги (Калашников "Ассемблер - это просто") . Не получилось собрать в .сом версию, так как линковщик выдает ошибку. оbj.файл создается без проблем. Зато получилось собрать в visual studio code, но там только .exe расширение. По крайней мере, настройки перерыл и не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

У вас код для COM файла, а собираете вы EXE. Для EXE файла нужно обязательно инициализировать регистр DS (как именно - смотрите в примерах кода для EXE), иначе там будет мусор, и при выполнении данные будут браться не оттуда, откуда вам нужно, а из какого-то другого места.

Либо собирайте в COM файл - для этого при запуске линкера (TLINK) нужно добавить опцию `/t`:

```
tlink /t T.obj
```